# Issue updating cell width in UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've got a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and I'm trying to update the cell size to always be the width of the screen. The cells aren't updating properly when I rotate to landscape. Here's my subclass:

```
// MARK: - Constants

private let EdgeInset: CGFloat = 10
private let CellSpacing: CGFloat = 10
private let LineSpacing: CGFloat = 10
private let CellHeight: CGFloat = 50

// MARK: - FullWidthLayout

class FullWidthLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        minimumLineSpacing = LineSpacing
        minimumInteritemSpacing = CellSpacing
        sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: EdgeInset, left: EdgeInset, bottom: EdgeInset, right: EdgeInset)
    }
}

// MARK: Layout Methods

extension FullWidthLayout {

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        if let view = collectionView {
            let availableWidth = view.bounds.width - EdgeInset * 2
            itemSize = CGSize(width: availableWidth, height: CellHeight)

            print("Item size: \(itemSize)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output in the console:

```
Item size: (300.0, 50.0)
Item size: (548.0, 50.0)
```

And here's what's happening in the simulator:

[image: portrait version of my app]

[image: landscape version of my app]

The item size seems to be set correctly in the `prepare()` method, but the cell doesn't update in the collection view. Exceptions are thrown if you start in landscape and move to portrait.

Is there something I'm missing? Is the base `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` ignoring the `itemSize` in some cases?

Here's a link to the project on GitHub: [CollectionViewRotate](https://github.com/mpdifran/CollectionViewRotate)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your ViewController

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/ 2 - 10, height: 100) // chnage as per your need ...10 is the space between cell
    }

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    myCollectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You only need to implement that delegate method if the layout can't figure out the item size on its own. It should be possible for the layout to set its own item size.